# getopt - how to avoid read next flag as argument?

Tags: bash, getopts

When I use getopt and pass the required flags with empty argument, it reads the next flag as an argument. Need assistance to add some sort of check to distinguish between flag containing dash (-) and double (--), otherwise identify it as an error and then call the Usage function.

`./test.sh -s -h`

Output:

```
 -s '-h' --

DBSTORE=-h
DBHOST=
```

Here's the code that I'm working on:

```
#!/bin/bash

################################################
# Usage function display how to run the script #
################################################
function usage(){
    cat << EOF
    Usage: ./test.sh [-s] <abc|def|ghi> [-h] <Hostname>

    This script does foo.
    OPTIONS:
        -H | --help         Display help options
        -s | --store STORE  OpenDJ Store type [abc|def|ghi]
        -h | --Host  HOST   Hostname of the servers
EOF
}

##########################################
# Parse short/long options with 'getopt' #
##########################################
function getOpts(){
    # Option strings:
    SHORT=s:h:H
    LONG=store:,host:,help
    # Read the options
    OPTS=$(getopt --options $SHORT --long $LONG --name "$0" -- "$@")

    if [ $? != 0 ]; then
        echo "Failed to parse options...!" >&2
        usage
        echo ""
        exit 1
    fi
    echo "$OPTS"
    eval set -- "$OPTS"

    # Set initial values:
    DBSTORE=
    DBHOST=
    HELP=false

    # Extract options and their arguments into variables:
    NOARG="true"
    while true; do
        case "$1" in
            -s | --store )
                            DBSTORE=$2;
                            shift 2
                            ;;
            -h | --host )
                            DBHOST="$2"
                            shift 2
                            ;;
            -H | --help )
                            usage
                            echo ""
                            shift
                            shift
                            exit 1
                            ;;
            -- )
                    shift
                    break
                    ;;
            \?)
                echo -e "Invalid option: -$OPTARG\n" >&2
                usage;
                echo ""
                exit 1
                ;;
            :) 
                echo -e "Missing argument for -$OPTARG\n" >&2
                usage;
                echo ""
                exit 1
                ;;
            *) 
                echo -e "Unimplemented option: -$OPTARG\n" >&2
                usage;
                echo ""
                exit 1
                ;;
      esac
      NOARG="false"
    done
    [[ "$NOARG" == "true" ]] && { echo "No argument was passed...!"; usage; echo ""; exit 1; }
}

getOpts "${@}"

echo DBSTORE=$DBSTORE
echo DBHOST=$DBHOST

exit 0
```

Comment: getopt != getopts

Comment: Do not use getopt, since `getopt`has been outdated since 1986 because of various design bugs that cannot be fixed. Use the shell builtin `getopts` instead.

Comment: I need to use "getopt" because "getopts" doesn't support --long option.

Comment: Why do you need long options?

Comment: It is not clear in this example, but in another example, I'm passing multiple flags where the automation script reads those long flags and logically adds arguments next to it before executing the script.